# Invalid markup for wpf UserControl xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

Today when i launch my project, all my views that contains `UserControl` have: `Invalid Markup` error.

```
   <UserControl x:Class="ProjectName.View.LeftMenuControl"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RaceFlightConfigurator.View"
                 xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
                 xmlns:UserControl="clr-namespace:ProjectName.View"
                 mc:Ignorable="d" 
                 d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UserControl:ConnectControl Margin="4"></UserControl:ConnectControl>

</UserControl>
```

I tried to `Rebuild solution`, remove `Shadow cache` folder from designer, etc. but nothing help...

Project works fine.

Comment: Is this in design mode or run mode? If the former then it could just be that your `ConnectControl` has something that's not initialised correctly at design time.

Comment: In design mode. User control has code: `public partial class LeftMenuControl : UserControl
    {
        public LeftMenuControl()
        {
            DataContext = new LeftMenuViewModel();
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }`

Comment: If it worked before today, what's changed in `ConnectControl`? Does something now (for example) require a database connection?

Comment: I just tested empty `UserControl`. Without code, etc. Same issue when i try to include it to `MainWindow` or other `Views`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution. I use Parallels on Mac, and my project was on `/Mac/Username/Document`s etc. When i moved project to `C:` path, all works.